# compare date-strings with timezone

Tags: java, date

I have a date-string like this:

```
2013-01-04T15:55:51.217+01:00
```

I can get a date like this:

```
2013-01-04T15:55:51
```

with SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").

But cant find something for the whole date-string with the milliseconds and Timezone.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: try `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

Comment: with ss.SSSZ I get "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS z")

Also, take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (I am assuming you are using Java 6)

Comment: this works: new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"); But im losing the information of the milliseconds.

Comment: It is likely that your original date didn't have milliseconds when it was initially created. Is that the case?

Comment: It does have milliseconds.

Comment: because you do have a date.. I do have a string which i convert to date (with parse) and on that way im losing the milliseconds.